# How to fade one component in while another fades out?

Tags: react-native, react-animated

In a class component, I have two views, one as a placeholder and one for image. The placeholder shows until some state changes (when the image finishes loading), and then the image shows. I am trying to add some animation and have the image fade-in and the placeholder fade-out when the state changes instead.

Below is the relevant render function for the two views:

```
renderImage = (filePath: string): JSX.Element => {
    const { isImageLoaded } = this.state;
    if (isImageLoaded) {
        return (
            <View style={Styles.imageContainer}>
                    <Image source={{ uri: filePath, cache: 'reload' }}/>
            </View>
        );
    }

    return (
        <View style={Styles.placeholderContainer}>
        </View>
    );
};
```

I understand I need to change the views to `Animated.View` and have fade-in/fade-out functions like so:

```
Animated.timing(this.state.opacity, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 500,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
```

Is the correct way to call the fade-in/fade-out functions in the callback of the `setState` for the `isImageLoaded` state? Or is there a way to trigger the animations without manually calling them in `setState` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can, I would recommend using `react-native-reanimated (v2)`. It has a feature exactly for this usecase using `entering` and `exiting` prop.
Example using reanimated:

```
if (shouldShow) {
   return(
      <Animated.View entering={FadeIn} exiting={FadeOut}>
         <Content/>
      </Animated.View>
   )
}
```

See: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6UXfS6FI674

If it's not possible, you have to build your own implementation. Could be something like this:

```
handleHideAnimation = () => {
   Animated.timing(value, {
      toValue: 0,
      duration: 500,
    }).start(() => handleUnmountComponent);
}
```

Comment: Also, don't forget to call `LayoutAnimation.ANIMATION_NAME();` if you are conditionally rendering two components